# Are there any standards followed to generate Hash Time Locked Contracts (HTLC) secrets (pre-image)?

Tags: contract-design, cryptography, decentralized-exchange

I am going to design and work on HTLC system. I wanted to know do these HTLC supporting exchanges or Decentralized exchanges have some kind of standard for pre-image? Its structure or anything. Or is it just a random thing?

Comment: Are you trying to atomic swaps between Ethereum and some other network?

Comment: Yes, thats what I am trying to do. Was just curious if there are some standards to follow.

Comment: AFAIK it is such new area that there is not much standards and even the research is still going on. Out of my hat I would recommend to check how tBTC and Keep network are doing these.